# What are the best methods to consume a web service from android?

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

Can anyone tell me which is the best, ease and flexible method to consume web service from android? I'm using eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only care about consuming a webservice, I assume you already know how to send data from the web server. Do you use JSON or XML, or any other kind of data format?

I myself prefer JSON, especially for Android.
Your question still lacks some vital information.

I personally use apache-mime4j and httpmime-4.0.1 libraries for web services.

With these libraries I use the following code

```
public void get(String url) {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    InputStream _inStream = null;
    HttpClient _client = null;
    try {

        _client = new DefaultHttpClient(_clientConnectionManager, _httpParams);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);

        httpResponse = _client.execute(get, _httpContext);
        this.setResponseCode(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if(entity != null) {
            _inStream = entity.getContent();
            this.setStringResponse(IOUtility.convertStreamToString(_inStream));
            _inStream.close();
            Log.i(TAG, getStringResponse());
        }
    } catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            _inStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
}
```

I make a request via _client.execute([method], [extra optional params])
The result from the request is put in a HttpResponse object.

From this object you can get the status code and the entity containing the result.
From the entity I take the content. The content would in my case be the actualy JSON string. You retrieve this as an InputStream, convert the stream to a string and do whatever you want with it.

For example

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(_webService.getStringResponse()); //getStringResponse is a custom getter/setter to retrieve the string converted from an inputstream in my WebService class.
```

Depending on how you build your JSON. mine is nested deeply with objects in the array etc. 
But handling this is basic looping.

```
JSONObject objectInResult = result.getJSONObject(count);//count would be decided by a while or for loop for example.
```

You can extract data from the current JSON object in this case like:

```
objectInResult.getString("name"); //assume the json object has a key-value pair that has name as a key.
```

Answer (score 0):

to parse "JSON" I recommend the following library is the faster and better.

[Jackson Java JSON-processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)